# Export animated user control as gif

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have made a user control i.e Circular progress bar now i want to export it as animated gif. How can i achieve this in .net.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to create a screenshot of it in every desired frame and them glue all the frames into the gif.

That's how you screenshot a control:

[screenshot of a winforms control through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674302/screenshoot-of-a-winforms-control-through-c-sharp)

That's how you prepare a gif:

[how to create an animated gif in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net)